# For each value of PC speed that exceeds 600 MHz, find out the average price of PCs with identical speeds. Result set: speed, average price

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, average

table is PC (code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
I used this query:

```
SELECT distinct speed, AVG(price) AS avg_price
FROM pc where speed > 600  group by speed,price
```

but it's showing

[image: actual result]

but correct output is

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calculating the average price per speed. By adding `price` to the `group by` clause, you're producing a distinct row per combination of `price` and `speed` (the average price, per price, being the price itself). Just drop it from there, and you should be fine:

```
SELECT   speed, AVG(price) AS avg_price
FROM     pc 
WHERE    speed > 600
GROUP BY speed
```

(BTW, using `distinct` on a group-by column isn't technically wrong, but it is superfluous).

Answer (score 1):

You need to group it by speed only, just remove the price part from the group by clause, like below:

```
SELECT speed, AVG(price) AS avg_price
FROM pc
WHERE speed > 600
GROUP BY speed
```

**EDIT:** Also, no need for distincting the rows as they will already be distinct because of how aggregating works.